# Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES) with google cloud MYSQL Instance

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I have created a google cloud MYSQL Instance and trying to load a CSV file into MYSQL using below query.

```
LOAD DATA  INFILE 'D:/test.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(title,@expired_date,amount)
SET expired_date = STR_TO_DATE(@expired_date, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

But getting below error.

Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to authenticate against your GCP MySQL instance? In this scenario, it would appear that it's not your query that's throwing this error, but the initial authentication instead.

Comment: Hi esqew, I'm using MySQL work bench to connect MySQL and I have created discounts  tables. Then after trying to execute this query in the same window to load data from csv file

Comment: (a) In your MySQL Workbench client, what have you included as the "host" parameter? I would not expect the `%` token to appear where the hostname for your MySQL instance should appear instead. (b) Is the `test.csv` file available on the machine hosting the MySQL instance? If the database is a managed instance in Google Cloud Platform, I would doubt this. The MySQL server you're attempting to run this query on likely has no idea what `D:\ ` refers to in your own machine's local context.

Comment: the host name for the root is %. And yes the file is on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be 1 or 2 problems at play here:

1. Authentication issues as esqew remarked
2. Privilege issues related to the query you try to execute

**Authentication issues**

Before we go the next step, I assume that you have been able to carry out SELECT queries with your root user on this CloudSQL server. If not, then it seems there is an authentication issue, and it would be best to check whether you are in possession of the correct 'root' user password. To change the password[1]:

> 1. Go to the Cloud SQL Instances page in the Google Cloud Console.
> 2. Click the instance to open its Overview page.
> 3. Select Users from the Navigation menu.
> 4. Find the root user with a Host value of % (any host) and select Change password from the more actions menu
> 5. Provide a strong password that you can remember and click Ok.

**Privilege issues**

By default the permissions of root user are limited on CloudSQL. This means the that the root user lacks the FILE and SUPER privileges you would have on most other servers[2]. In order to carry out the `LOAD DATA INFILE` query mentioned above, there are two important points to consider:

1. mysql makes the assumption that the file is located on the server[3, the point starting with "If `LOCAL` is not specified]." Since the cloudSQL servers run on Linux, a path starting with `D:\` does not make much sense to the server.
2. `LOAD DATA INFILE` requires the FILE permission that CloudSQL does not provide to the root user. Hence, you will not have permission to carry out this query[4].

To prevent the permission issue, and carry out loading the data from the local machine as intended, you are allowed to use the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement on CloudSQL[5], and use the local path you specified above (also see [3]).

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users#user-root

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#root-user

[3] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-file

[4] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file

[5] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing